# How can i read inputs till user decide to end

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can i write in python a code which will be doing excatly the same thing as:

```
while(cin>>a){//some operations on "a"}
```

in c++? I try:

```
while(a=raw_input()):
```

but IDLE throws a syntax error on "=". I don't want to use

```
while True:
```

Answer (score 5):

Use an iterator with a sentinel:

```
for a in iter(raw_input, ""):
    # do stuff with a
```

this will keep running the first argument to `iter` (`raw_input()`) until the result (`a`) is equal to the second argument (`""`). This way the loop terminates when the user just presses enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ' '
while a:  # loop exits when user just hits <ENTER>
    a=raw_input()
    # do stuff with a
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error IDLE gives on '=' is that in a conditional statement it needs to be '==', as in

```
while a == raw_input(''):
    code code code
```